# add linear trend back into time series prediction (in R)

Tags: r, time-series, garch, prediction-interval, volatility-forecasting

I have the following GARCH(1,1) model

```
ymod1 = lm(Jobs ~ Month, df)
resid =ymod1$residuals

library(fGarch)
fit = garchFit(~garch(1,1), cond.dist="sged",  data= resid ,trace=F)
```

I plotted the expected values with a confidence interval based on the variance predicted by my GARCH model using the predict function:

```
predict(fit, n.ahead = 12, plot=TRUE,conf=.9,nx=100)
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/At3C8.png

But it has plotted it on the residuals of a linear trend that I removed, instead of the actual data. How do I obtain a confidence interval for the actual data and plot it on that instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are interested in *prediction intervals* (applicable to outcomes of a random variable) rather than *confidence intervals* (applicable to parameters or their combinations), I presume.

Add `Month` as an external regressor to the mean equation when specifying the GARCH model. I am not sure whether `garchFit` has the functionality, but `ugarchspec` and `ugarchfit` from the `rugarch` package certainly do. In the function `ugarchspec`, there is an argument `external.regressors` within `mean.model` for putting `Month` into. See the [documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/rugarch/versions/1.4-2/topics/ugarchspec-methods).

Alternatively, just add the fitted values from `ymod1` to each end of the prediction intervals that you have obtained for the GARCH model on the residuals from `ymod1`.

Comment: Note: asking for code is off-topic, but I gave you the core ideas for writing it yourself.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Is this what you had in mind for using rugarch?        
 garchspec <- ugarchspec(mean.model = list(armaOrder = c(0,0) + df$Month),
variance.model = list(model = "sGARCH"), distribution.model = "sged")
garchfit <- ugarchfit(data = timeseries , spec = garchspec) . When I do this I get an ar1, ma1, and ma2 term added to the model, are these necessary in the model to account for the linear trend?

Comment: @user553480, you have specified `armaOrder` incorrectly. There is a separate argument `external.regressors` within `mean.model` for putting `Month` into. See the [documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/rugarch/versions/1.4-2/topics/ugarchspec-methods). You may also consider including `Month` as a regressors in the conditional variance equation; perhaps the conditional variance has some `Month`-related variation to it.

Comment: Thank you. With that in mind, is this the correct way to specify the model if I wish to add the linear trend into the mean component? garchspec = ugarchspec(variance.model=list(model="sGARCH", garchOrder=c(1,1)), 
  mean.model=list(armaOrder=c(0,0), external.regressors = matrix(df$Month)),  
  distribution.model="sged") garchfit <- ugarchfit(data = timeseries, spec = garchspec)

Comment: @user553480, if `matrix(df$Month)` is a linear trend, then yes.

Comment: It is a matrix of month 1 to 112, as my observations were taken over 112 months.

Comment: @user553480, that sounds fine.

Comment: Great, thanks alot for your help

Comment: @user553480, you are welcome!